# How to Modify My Plugin's Admin Settings so that the Plugin can be Added to a Specific Page?

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I have written a registration plugin for a very specific use case.  The form contains several hundred lines of HTML.  The intent for the form is to be able to add it to a given page by way of Admin settings.  I've written the following to achieve this:

```
<?php
 /**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: me
 * Date: 7/10/16
 * Time: 9:42 PM
 */

?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo esc_html(get_admin_page_title()); ?></h2>
<?php
    $options = get_option('QFPMembership');
    settings_fields('QFPMembership');
?>
<form method="post" name="qfpregister-settings" action="options.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="screen-reader-text"><span><?php _e('Registration Module', 'QFPMembership'); ?></span></legend>
        <label for="qpfmembership-registration">
            <?php echo home_url('/');?><input type="text" id="qfpmembership-registration" name="QFPMembership[registration]" value="<?php echo $options['registration'];?>" />
            <span><?php esc_attr_e('Registration Module', 'QFPMembership'); ?></span><br>
            <span class="description"><?php esc_attr_e('The registration form will be added to the end of this page.', 'QFPMembership'); ?></span>
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <?php submit_button('Save', 'primary', 'submit', TRUE); ?>
    </form>
  </div>
 <?php
 function qfpmembership_admin_display(){
    add_options_page( 'QFP Registration Settings', 'QFP Registration 
    Module Settings', 'manage_options', 'qfpregister_settings',     
    'qfp_membership_admin_display');
 }

function display_qfpregister_settings(){
    add_action('admin_menu', 'qfpregister_settings_page');
}

function registration_template($page_template){
   $options = get_option('QFPRegistration');
   if(is_page( $options['membership-pageacghjlmrsvy-'])){
        $page_template = dirname(__FILE__ ) . '/public/partials
        /registrationform.php';
   }
   return $page_template;
}
add_filter( 'page_template', 'user_profile_template', 11);
```

I've written the following class to tap into the Settings API:

```
class QFPRegistration_Admin
{
   /**
    * The ID of this plugin.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    * @access private
    * @var     string      $plugin_name    The ID of this plugin.
    */
    private $plugin_name;

    /**
    * The version of the plugin.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    * @access private
    * @var     string      $version    The current version of the plugin.
    */
    private $version;

    /**
    * Initialize the class and it's properties.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    * @param   string      $plugin_name    The name of the plugin.
    * @param   string      $version        The version of the plugin
    */
    public function __construct($plugin_name, $version)
    {
    $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
    $this->version = $version;
    }

    /**
    * Register the stylesheet for the admin area.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
    public function enqueue_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__) . 'css/QFPMembershipAdmin.css', array(), $this->version, 'all');
    }

    /**
    * Register the Javascript for the admin area.
    *
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
    public function enqueue_scripts(){
       wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/QFPMembershipAdmin.js', array( 'jquery'), $this->version, false);
    }

    /**
    * Register the administration menu into the Wordpress Dashboard menu.
    * @since 1.0.0
    */
    public function add_plugin_admin_menu(){
    /*
     * Add settings  page for this plugin to the settings menu.
     * 
     */
    add_options_page('QFP Registration Module Setup', 'QFPRegistration',  'manage_options', $this->plugin_name, array($this, 'display_plugin_setup_page')
    );
   }   

   /**
   * Add settings action links to the plugin page.
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
   public function add_action_links( $links ){
    $settings_link = array(
        '<a href="' . admin_url( 'options-general-php?page=' . $this->plugin_name) . '">' . __('Settings', $this->plugin_name) . '</a>',
    );
    return array_merge( $settings_link, $links );
   }

   /**
   * Render the settings page for the QFPMembership plugin.
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
   public function display_plugin_setup_page(){
    include_once('partials/qfpregistration-admin-display.php');
   }

   /**
   * Save the plugin options
   * @since 1.0.0
   */
   public function options_update(){
    register_setting( $this->plugin_name, $this->plugin_name, array($this, 'validate') );
    }
 }
```

When I install the plugin into my local Wordpress instance, I go to the QFPMembership Settings and specify the page on which the form is to be inserted.  I press Save and then view the page in question, and the form is not inserted.

What must be modified / augmented in order to ensure the registration form is properly inserted on the page I designate?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your problem is. Have you try to build the admin settings page using the [Settngs API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/)?

Comment: @cybmeta Yes.  Please see my edited post.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering `user_profile_template` function to run during the `page_template` filter hook, but your function is actually called `registration_template`.

This is why your selected page might not be loading your custom template file. That's one thing. Another is that with this method, the selected page will look completely different than all other page in the active theme. While you can mimic one theme's HTML structure in your plugin's custom template, this will not work in other themes. That's assuming that your custom page template should look like it's a part of the theme (with header and footer, at least). A workaround would be adding a filter to `the_content` hook and printing your custom HTML before, after or instead of the original content. This way you are only concerned with your own markup and you're letting the active theme to control the overall HTML structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Could elaborate a bit further as to your proposed workaround?